# Best practice for collections in jsons: array vs dict/map

Tags: python, json

I need to pass data in a python back-end to a front end through an api call, using a json format. In the python back end, the data is in a dictionary structure, which I can easily and directly convert to a json. But should I?

My front-end developer believes the answer is no, for reasons related to best practice.

But I challenge that:

Is the best to structure a json as it is in python, or should it rather be converted to some other form, such as several arrays (as would be necessary in my example case below)?

Or, differently put:

What should be the governing principles related to collections/dicts/maps/arrays for interfacing information through jsons?

I've done some googling for an answer, but I've not come across much that addresses this directly. Links would be appreciated.

(Note about the example below: of course if the data is written to a database, it would probably make most sense for the front-end to access the database directly, but let's assume this is not the case)

Example:

In the back end there is a collection of objects called `pets`:
each item in the collection has a unique `pet_id`, some non-optional properties, e.g. `name` and `date_of_birth`, some optional properties  `registration_certificate_nr`, `adopted_from_kennel`, some lists like `siblings` and `children` and some objects like `medication`.

Assuming that the front end needs all of this info at some point, it could be

```
{
  "pets": {
    "17-01-24-01": {
      "name": "Buster",
      "date_of_birth": "04/01/2017",
      "registration_certificate_nr": "AAD-1123-1432"
    },
    "17-03-04-01": {
      "name": "Hooch",
      "date_of_birth": "05/02/2015",
      "adopted_from_kennel": "Pretoria Shire",
      "children": [
        "17-05-01-01",
        "17-05-01-02",
        "17-05-01-03"
      ]
    },
    "17-05-01-01": {
      "name": "Snappy",
      "date_of_birth": "17-05-01",
      "siblings": [
        "17-05-01-02",
        "17-05-01-03"
      ]
    },
    "17-05-01-02": {
      "name": "Gizmo",
      "date_of_birth": "17-05-01",
      "siblings": [
        "17-05-01-01",
        "17-05-01-03"
      ]
    },
    "17-05-01-03": {
      "name": "Toothless",
      "date_of_birth": "17-05-01",
      "siblings": [
        "17-05-01-01",
        "17-05-01-03"
      ],
      "medication": [
        {
          "name": "anti-worm",
          "code": "aw445",
          "dosage": "1 pill per day"
        },
        {
          "name": "disinfectant",
          "code": "pdi-2",
          "dosage": "as required"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your co-worker's rationale for structuring it differently? How do they want it and why?

Comment: It doesn't make the least bit of difference. The only argument I could see is if the front-end code already expects an array: don't change your backend API solely for your own convenience.

Comment: @JohnKugelman , I’ll let my brother coertgrobbelaar represent his view himself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON formatting is a somewhat subjective matter, and related disagreements are usually best settled between colleagues. 
That being said, there are some potentially valid criticisms to be made against the JSON format in the question, especially if we are trying to create a consistent, RESTful API.

The 2 pain points that stand out:

1. A map collection is represented in JSON, which isn't really JSON standard compliant, or particularly RESTful.
2. None of the pet objects have an `id` defined. There is a `pet_id` mentioned in the question, but it seems to be maintained separately from the pet object itself. If a value is accessed in the `pets` map in the question, a user of the API would have to manually add the `pet_id` to the provided pet object in order to have the id available further down the line, when the full JSON may no longer be available.

The closest things we have to guiding standards in this situation is the [REST architectural style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and the [JSON standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

---

We can start by looking at the JSON standard. Here is a quote from the [JSON wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Unsupported_native_data_types):

> JavaScript syntax defines several native data types that are not included in the JSON standard: Map, Set, Date, Error, Regular Expression, Function, Promise, and `undefined`.

The key takeaway here is that JSON is not meant to represent the map data type. Python dictionaries are a map implementation, so directly serializing a dictionary to JSON with the intent to represent a map-like collection goes against the intended use of JSON.

For an individual object like a pet, the JSON object is appropriate, but for collections there is one option: the JSON array. There is a usage example with the JSON array further down in this answer.

There may be edge cases where deviating from the standard makes sense, but I don't see a reason in this scenario.

---

There are also some shortcomings in the JSON format from a RESTful design perspective. RESTful API design is nice because it encourages one to keep things simple and consistent. It also happens to be a de facto industry standard.

In a RESTful HTTP API, this is how fetching a single pet resource should look:

```
Request: GET /api/pets/17-01-24-01

Response: 200 {
    "id": "17-01-24-01",
    "name": "Buster",
    "date_of_birth": "04/01/2017",
    "registration_certificate_nr": "AAD-1123-1432"
}
```

The response is a completely defined resource with an explicitly defined `id`. It is also the simplest complete JSON representation of a pet.

Next, we define what fetching multiple pet resources looks like, assuming only 2 pets are defined:

```
Request: GET /api/pets

Response: 200 [
    {
        "id": "17-01-24-01",
        "name": "Buster",
        "date_of_birth": "04/01/2017",
        "registration_certificate_nr": "AAD-1123-1432"
    },
    {
        "id": "17-03-04-01",
        "name": "Hooch",
        "date_of_birth": "05/02/2015",
        "adopted_from_kennel": "Pretoria Shire",
        "children": [
            "17-05-01-01",
            "17-05-01-02",
            "17-05-01-03"
         ]
    }
]
```

The above response format is the most straight forward way to pluralize the single resource response format, thus keeping the API as simple and consistent as possible. (for the sake of brevity, I only used 2 of the sample resources from the question). Once again, the `id`s are explicitly defined, and belong to their respective pet objects.

Nothing is gained from adding map keys to the above format.

Proponents of the JSON format in the question may suggest to just add the `id` field into each pet object in order to work around pain point 2, but that would raise the question of repeating data within the response. Why does the `id` need to be both inside and outside the object? Surely it should only be on the inside? After eliminating the redundant data, the result will look like the response above.

That is the REST argument. There are use cases where REST doesn't really work, but this is far from that.

---

PS. Front ends should never access databases directly. The API is responsible for writing to and reading from whatever data persistence infrastructure is used. In a lot of bigger real world systems, there is even an additional BFF layer between the front end and the API(s), separating the front end and the DB even further.

Comment: Another way that I explain it to myself is that the "fundamental" difference between an array of pets and a map of pets is that, when using an array, it is self-evident that each item in the collection represents an entity of the same type. With the dict format, this is not implicit: it has the same representation in a json as an object with various properties.

Comment: Well written - thanks for that. Other points supporting using arrays - (1) as the list of pets get larger, you would likely want to add pagination and other such filtering, which makes more sense in an array. (2) Iterating over object/map can be fickle - various js frameworks may iterate over the object in different order giving unexpected behavior (this is taken from Vue v-for docs)